# Can't format(self) JSON to fill in information

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
data = '{{"user": "{{0.user}}", "pass": "{{0.pass}}", "code": "123456789"}}'
data = data.format(self)
data = json.dumps(data)
print(data)
```

Attempted to escape the {}'s to see if that would help but it still doesn't fill in the information. It prints out "{0.user}" and "{0.pass}" rather than filling them with the data.

.format(self) works fine if it's more in a POST type ex:

```
data = "user={0.user}&pass={0.pass}"
data = data.format(self)
print(data)
```

Is it the outside {}'s? What do I do?

Comment: What is self on the second line of code?

Comment: `{{` means a litteral `{` - just use one, as in `'{{"user": "{0.user}", ...`. Also, note that you can't use `pass` or any other keyword as an attribute name.

Comment: But I don't get what your goal is. If you want a dict, just create it as a dict. If you want a JSON representation of your dict, create it and use json to create the string. Do you really intend to get a JSON representation of the string that represents your dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> {{ means a litteral { - just use one, as in '{{"user": "{0.user}", .... Also, note that you can't use pass or any other keyword as an attribute name.

This helped and resolved the issue.

```
data = '{{"user": "{0.user}", "pass": "{0.pass}", "code": "123456789"}}'
```

Was the correct way and worked fine.